# Does inserting into a Cassandra unset cell create a tombstone?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to enable invalidation of old measurements while keeping them in my Cassandra setup. Given the following table structure:

```
ID|Test|result|valid|valid2
1 | 1  |  10  | False| unset
2 | 1  |  11  | True| False
3 | 1  |  12  | True| True
```

with primary key (ID,test)

Now if I insert the following SparkDataframe using the connector as normal with mode("append")

```
ID|Test|valid2
1 | 1  | False
```

Will this create a tombstone? The purpose is to be able to "invalidate" certain rows in my tables when necessary. I understand tombstones are created when cells are outdated. But since there is no value in the cell, will a tombstone be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tombstones are created when you performing explicit DELETE, insert `null` value, or data is TTLed.

If you don't specify the value for specific column, then the data for this cell is simply not set, and if you had some previous data before, then they won't be overwritten until you explicitly set them to `null`.  But in Spark, usually situation is different - by default it will insert nulls until you won't specify `spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls` as `true` - in this case it will treat nulls as unset, and won't owerwrite the previous data.

But when you specify incomplete row, then only provided pieces will be updated, keeping the previous data intact.

If we have following table and data:

```
create table test.v2(id int primary key, valid boolean, v int);
insert into test.v2(id, valid, v) values(2,True, 2);
insert into test.v2(id, valid, v) values(1,True, 1);
```

we can check that data is visible in Spark:

```
scala> val data = spark.read.cassandraFormat("v2", "test").load()
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, v: int ... 1 more field]

scala> data.show
+---+---+-----+
| id|  v|valid|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  1| true|
|  2|  2| true|
+---+---+-----+
```

Now update the data:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

scala> val newData = Seq((2, false)).toDF("id", "valid")
newData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, valid: boolean]

scala> newData.write.cassandraFormat("v2", "test").mode(SaveMode.Append).save()

scala> data.show
+---+---+-----+
| id|  v|valid|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  1| true|
|  2|  2|false|
+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: I need to retain the "invalid" rows as the flag simply indicates what should be considered for some analysis later. However I have had issues with using a single column as a "processing status" flag not being updated even when the "write" is complete with the proper consistency level of Quorum set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834477/cassandra-maintain-a-processing-column-non-acid-behavior-is-not-breaking-but-th
As such I was thinking of using multiple columns instead.
This leads to the issue that I cannot guarantee an upsert is completed, hence the additional column.

Comment: the question is - do you need old data or not?

Comment: I need the data. Cant delete it.

Comment: If you don't supply a value for a cell, you get "nothing" - not even a tombstone. However, if you specify the cell and insert null/nothing into it, you will get a tombstone for that cell. It doesn't seem like from your above description that you're doing the latter.

Comment: @Alex Ott Thanks for the answer. so if I only insert on the "unset" column for a particular key it works like a blank write.

Comment: it looks like - at least I see this behavior in my test.

Comment: @ Alex Ott Thanks. Will accept your answer for now, If my tests show differently I will post a follow-up.